# Use of RTRIM() function

Tags: sql-server

We use `RTRIM()` to trim any extra spaces appended to right side of any word. But in MS SQL server 2012 I am finding SSMS is automatically trimming any extra spaces to the right side of any word. Please find the below query for our case understanding.

Query:-

```
DECLARE @INPUT AS TABLE
(
NAME VARCHAR(20),
PRODUCTID INT,
SHIP_DATE DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO @INPUT(NAME,PRODUCTID,SHIP_DATE) VALUES('BRITANIA    ',1,'2017-07-08')
INSERT INTO @INPUT(NAME,PRODUCTID,SHIP_DATE) VALUES('    NESTLE',2,'08-07-2017')

--SELECT * FROM @INPUT

SELECT RTRIM(LTRIM(NAME)),LEN(RTRIM(LTRIM(NAME))),NAME, LEN(NAME) FROM @INPUT

SELECT 'BRITANIA     ',LEN('BRITANIA   ')
```

If you run this above query in MS SQL Server 2012 then all extra spaces have been automatically removed for the word 'BRITANIA'. So, this means MS SQL server 2012 is making  `RTRIM()` function inutile. `RTRIM()` seems of no use here.
I have tried with previous version and found same results.

I checked in Toad application running Oracle 10g and I found RTRIM() works properly.

```
SELECT RTRIM(LTRIM(NAME)),LEN(RTRIM(LTRIM(NAME))),NAME, LEN(NAME) FROM DUAL
```

Can you please explain me why SSMS is producing such output for `RTRIM()` function and without `RTRIM()` function ?

```
SELECT 'BRITANIA     ',LEN('BRITANIA     ') AS [WITHOUT RTRIM], LEN(RTRIM('BRITANIA     ')) AS [WITH RTRIM]
```

If you execute this above query in MS SQL server 2012 then it is automatically trimming extra spaces towards left and producing only the size of the given word.

Kindly, answer me on this regards.

Thanks

Comment: [Behavior of Varchar with spaces at the end](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10510/behavior-of-varchar-with-spaces-at-the-end)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already posted, the behavior is normal:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10510/behavior-of-varchar-with-spaces-at-the-end

For your test, mention the difference between

> LEN() 
>   "returns the number of characters of the specified string expression,
>   excluding trailing blanks"

and

> DATALENGTH()
>   "returns the number of bytes used to represent any expression"

you can check it with this SQL:

```
SELECT 'BRITANIA     '
      ,LEN('BRITANIA   ')               AS LEN_function
      ,DATALENGTH('BRITANIA   ')        AS Datalength_function
UNION ALL
SELECT RTRIM('BRITANIA     ')
      ,LEN(RTRIM('BRITANIA   '))        AS LEN_function
      ,DATALENGTH(RTRIM('BRITANIA   ')) AS Datalength_function
```